# Add hidden data in ExpandableListView childs

Tags: android

Is it possible to add hidden data to the items of an ExpandableListView?
For example, in HTML I would do something like create a new attribute and than, get it from the selected item using JavaScript.

```
<select>
      <option hidden-data="298">Submenu 1</option>
</select>
```

For now, I can only get the text from the child and I need to pass an ID for each child to search the database for the right information.
Something like:

```
listDataHeader.add("Menu 1");

List<String> menu1 = new ArrayList<String>();
menu1.add("Submenu 1").addExtraData("ID = 23");
menu1.add("Submenu 2").addExtraData("ID = 24");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i don't know about the hidden values but you can add values related to list using HashMap. Code is given below. You can do something like that

```
 HashMap<String, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
...
...
menu1.add("SubMenu1");
hashMap.put("Submenu1",23);
..
```

You can retrieve the Id of "SubMenu1" using-

```
int id=hashMap.get("Submenu1");
```

After that use that id.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign an Object type to any View, by using its `setTag(Object object)` method. Later you can get this object by using the View's `getTag()` method, and casting it to the type you want.

If you don't want to store the data on the views, because it is not related to the views themselves, but more to the data, you could use the `android.util.Pair` (or `android.support.v4.util.Pair`) class, like this:

```
List<Pair<String,String>> menu1 = new ArrayList<Pair<String,String>>();
menu1.add(new Pair<String,String>("Submenu 1","ID = 23"));
menu1.add(new Pair<String,String>("Submenu 2","ID = 24"));

// Later you can get the data this way:
Pair<String, String> example = menu1.get(0);
String firstPart = example.first;
String extraInfo = example.second;
```